# Pinging local IPs with python

Tags: python, cmd, ping

im trying to write a function to ping multiple IP adreses connected with a LAN to my PC

my is :

'''

```
def ping_ip (ip):

pingResponse = os.system("ping " + ip + " -n 1")

if pingResponse == 0:

    return "Pass"

else:

    return "Fail"

def ping_all_ips ():

global allIPs

for ip in allIPs:

    result = ping_ip(ip)

    print(f"Attempt To Ping {ip} -----> {result}")
```

'''

but the problem is that i get "Pass" even when IP is not connected because it counts "Reply from XXXX: Destination net unreachable" as a success

Edit: tried with subprocess module as follows:

```
def ping_ip (ip):

    process = subprocess.Popen("ping " + ip + " -n 1" , shell=True stdoutt=subprocess.PIPE)

    for line in process.stdout:

        if b"Destination" in line or b"Request timed out" in line:

            return "Fail"

        else:

            return "Pass"

def ping_all_ips ():

    global allIPs

    for ip in allIPs:

        result = ping_ip(ip)

         print(f"Attempt To Ping {ip} -----> {result}")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ping_all_ips()
```

Comment: You could use the module `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `os.system()` and capture the output the is currently going to the terminal, then examine that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you want to check output from console but can see how. The solution is to use `subprocess` module like this.

```
import subprocess

allIPs = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.203", "192.168.1.23"]
def ping_ip (ip):
     process = subprocess.Popen("ping " + ip , shell=True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
     for line in process.stdout:
        print(line)
        if b"PING" in line:
            continue
        if b"Destination" in line or b"Request timed out" in line: 
            print("failed")
            process.kill()
            return "Fail"
        else:            
            print("passed")
            process.kill()
            return "Pass"
        
def ping_all_ips (): 
    global allIPs
    for ip in allIPs:
        print(f"Attempt To Ping {ip}") 
        result = ping_ip(ip)
        print(f"Attempt To Ping {ip} -----> {result}") 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    ping_all_ips()
```

this code will open a new process to run your command and check each line of output if it find `Destination` in output which means that an error has occurred it will print error and kill process. You can then add your logic if everything is ok and remember to always kill the process since `ping` will run forever if not stopped.

Comment: Why do i need to kill the process if im only using ping -n 1? Or is that not possible with this module?

Comment: @BenPinhas you are right I meant in my code example above you have to kill it but since you use ```-n 1``` the process will exit by itself.

Comment: Ive tried this solution, but yet i just get pass on every ping attempt..

Comment: @BenPinhas did you copy and paste the above code exactly since it's working on my machine

Comment: Sorry it looks a bit messy but im on my phone, ive edited the post to show my new code

Comment: @BenPinhas the problem is that the first line of ping output is just a summery of what the process does example (always ```PING 192.168.1.205 (192.168.1.205) 56(84) bytes of data.\n```) whatever the host exists or not so you need to ignore this first line of output make decisions on lines that actually say if host is online or not.

Comment: @BenPinhas edited the answer with a quick fix, this way it it doesn't make decisions on first line of ping